# Can I access anything in memory?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

Disclaimer: I am new to C/C++.

If I were to [manually assign a memory address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532000/how-to-assign-pointer-address-manually-in-c-programming-language) to a variable in C, and then try to echo out that value...do I have unrestricted access to view **anything** in memory or are there restrictions in place?

For example:

```
char * p = (char *)0x28ff44;
printf("Memory value: %c", *p);
```

I'm guessing that would crash horribly if what was at that address didn't fit the size of char type, but it's merely an example. What I really am curious about is if something like this is possible or do operating systems impose restrictions and only allow you to access memory in your given memory space?

Comment: You can find some interesting info at another question on stack overflow: http://superuser.com/questions/189876/how-os-detects-memory-access-violations

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the great answers. I remember trying to learn C back in high school (about 10+ years ago now I guess) and I seem to recall that at the time I was dabbling, there was usually one memory space and issues could occur within it. It's good to see there is more protection in place now for low-level noobs like myself.

Comment: Side note, `%s` is the wrong format string for a single character, you need `%c` ;)

Comment: The C standard does not allow it (it is "undefined behaviour"), but specific platforms may very well accept this in a sensible manner. For example, when you write an OS that is loaded by the BIOS, you will *have* to access certain hard-coded parts of memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh my, well.

Technically, yes, you can. In embedded devices which don't use a MMU or any form of protection (or, you know, x86 in real mode), you can do exactly what you have posted there. You can also do it in user mode on any operating system, but the chances of you actually hitting valid memory are very small.

In reality, no, you can't just do that. Given virtual memory and memory protection, it's very likely that the region you try to access will not have been mapped and hence, will fail. In addition, if you hit protected memory (e.g. anything belonging to the OS), your access will fail. Both of these scenarios are what cause segmentation faults.

Your statement is valid (for varying definitions of valid), and the program will try to access the memory you requested. It's just that it might not actually be mapped to anything.

It's worth also noting that this is how memory mapped I/O works. Say I have a hardware control register which when written to, writes a byte over the attached UART/serial line (and, for simplicity, it works as magic and doesn't need any other registers to be set). In C, this would be written as follows for my overly simplified device:

```
#define UART1_OUT 0xFC56   

volatile char* uart = UART1_OUT;   // Definition of pointer to variable.
                                   // volatile is required here. Look it up, but
                                   // it basically stops your compiler optimising
                                   // anything to do with this variable

*uart = 'A';                       // Write an A character to the serial line
```

Of course, real-world devices are a little more complex ;).

Comment: I guess you have to type cast the address value, else the compiler will give an error.

Comment: Nope, it's a warning by default in GCC. I'm not sure about Visual C and Clang.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what computer architecture and operating system your program runs on. Modern operating systems have the concept of [protected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection) and [virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paged_virtual_memory) memory. With virtual memory, memory addresses don't refer to physical memory, but rather to a virtual memory space assigned to the current application. Attempting to read or write to memory outside the assigned memory space will in these cases lead to a program fault (generally a segmentation fault, or protection fault).

Comment: So some OS's allow this kind of blatant intrusion into the memory space of other applications and/or the OS itself?

Comment: Ah ok. So with virtual memory, I could not "accidentally" crash other programs or the OS?

Comment: @cillosis: no, because the memory space of your process is not shared with any other processes

Answer (score 1):

Systems with a Memory Management Unit (MMU) are very likely to not let you access arbitrary memory. Any modern OS uses memory protection. But in the embedded sector there are many OSs that do not employ memory protection and where it is indeed possible to access any adressable memory.

Answer (score 1):

> If I were to manually assign a memory address to a variable in C, and
>   then try to echo out that value...do I have unrestricted access to
>   view anything in memory or are there restrictions in place?

The C language is happy to let you try that, but most operating systems won't let you access memory outside your process's memory space. If you're writing code for an embedded system where there's not much between your code and the hardware, you'll probably be able to read from and write to any location you like. If you're writing code for a system with protected memory, though, not so much.

> I'm guessing that would crash horribly if what was at that address
>   didn't fit the size of char type

Nah... the compiler doesn't care what type of data is stored at any given address. When you say `(char *)0x28ff44` you're telling it that `0x28ff44` is a `char *`, and that's good enough for the compiler. Your code might still crash for other reasons, though, like if `0x28ff44` isn't a valid address.