# How can I access data that is stored in the last byte of the physical memory using pointers?

Tags: c

How can I make a pointer point to the last byte of 
the physical memory and access its data?
Is this even possible?

Comment: [One step closer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532000/how-to-assign-pointer-address-manually-in-c-programming-language)

Comment: You need to be inside the kernel with paging disabled (or do some hardcore magic with MM unit).

Comment: @Aneri Such as, opening the /dev/mem file under linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since the language C does not specify the underlying memory architecture.

On select OS/architecture you may in an OS dependent or creative fashion.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible when memory is not protected, like in a small embedded system.
An Arduino with its AVR processor is an example where you can do that.

```
#define MEMORY_SIZE 1024 // 1 KB

char* lastBytePtr = (char*)(MEMORY_SIZE-1);
char lastByteValue = *lastBytePtr;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not possible. Modern operating systems have mappings between application memory and physical memory. It is possible to do it if you write a kernel (system) function, but then you need to specify which operating system you are using.