# Assigning an array to an address and printing values

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-address

I need to do the following:

Assume that the C++ array

```
int fib[] = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21 };
```

is stored on a 32-bit machine, at memory address 0xA0000000 (hexadecimal). What are the values of the following expressions?

```
  fib     
  *fib     
  &fib[0]     
  &fib[6]     
  *(fib+7)
```

I tried writing this code to try and print out the desired values.

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int *p = &A0000000;
    cout << "i= " << i << endl;
    cout << "p= " << p << endl;
    *p = 0;
    cout << "i=" << i << endl;

    int &r = i;
    r = 0;
    cout << "i= " << i << endl;


    int fib[] = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21 };
    cout << "fib= " << fib << endl;

    cout << "*(*fib)= "  << *fib     <<  endl;
    cout << "&fib[0]= "  << &fib[0]  <<  endl;
    cout << "*(fib+7)= " << *(fib+7) <<  endl;
    cout << "&fib[6]= "  << &fib[6]  <<  endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
c:\users\inquirer\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\fib1\fib1\fib1.cpp(7): error C2065: 'A0000000' : undeclared identifier
```

Thank you in advance for the help. What do I need to do to print out the correct values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532000/how-to-assign-pointer-address-manually-in-c-programming-language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the compilation error try

```
int* p=(int*)0xA0000000;
```

Whatever this should be good for ...

Comment: This is what it said: 'fib1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Inquirer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\fib1\Debug\fib1.exe', Symbols loaded.
'fib1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'fib1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'fib1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'fib1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'fib1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store something at an arbitrary virtual memory address.

`*p = 0;` will crash at runtime, because 0xa0000000 is probably not a valid location to write to.

Try `int *p = new int` and print the address you got. It will be less beautiful than 0xa0000000 but it will be sufficient to visuallise your experiment.

Comment: _'You cannot store something at an arbitrary virtual memory address.'_ That's plain wrong, and it would be very bad if you couldn't do so (that would give me a hard time interfacing a FPGA register interface on the EBI). You cannot in MPU protected systems or OS's that run processes in virtual memory environments!

Comment: @g-makulik I'm not so good with the C++ standard, but I'm pretty sure it will say something like implementation defined (I would tend to guess even undefined). That means generally you can not dereference an arbitrary "number". OP is on Windows where this will not work (without WinAPI help and luck that the virtual address is not already reserved).

Comment: It's still plain wrong what you're saying about storing/reading arbitrary address values. It **is possible** in C++ syntax, and the OP asked for a compile time error! So your answer is one step beyond the question.

Comment: **Please!** It's **really** plain wrong what you're saying here: _'You cannot store something at an arbitrary virtual memory address.'_ You can, and that's one of the great advantages of the C++ language, even if that's beyond your scope of using it!