# Assign integer literal to pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

This question might be too bad but I can take risk to post this question here to address my confusion.

Actually my question is that we can only assign address to pointer like :-

```
int *p,a;
p = &a; // OK
p = 1; // Error because you cannot assign integer literal to p*
```

But we can assign NULL to p like :

```
p = NULL;
```

Indeed, NULL is a macro which is value is 0 and before compiling this code by compiler it get replaced with 0 by prepocessor. So after replacement its look like

```
 p = 0;
```

I know it means p is point to nothing but according to rule we can only assign address to pointer but 0 is an integer.
So this isn't break the rule ?

Thanks.

Comment: i think The constant 0 is always the null pointer.

Comment: @barakmanos actually you are typecasting 1 to int* but not assign integer to p

Comment: Answers to this are different for C and C++. You can't program in 2 languages at once, pick one.

Comment: @DevSolar It's not only the casts. The definition of NULL is different in the two languages, especially if C++11 is considered.

Answer (score 5):

barak manos already pointed it out in his comment:

If you want to set a pointer to a literal value, you need to cast the literal value to the corresponding pointer type first.

`NULL` could just as well be defined as `(void *) 0`... which is implicitly convertible to *any* pointer type.

In either case, you end up with a pointer pointing to a literal address.

In no case, however, does your pointer point to memory *containing* a literal `4`, though. This is, to my knowledge, not possible without assigning that literal value to an `int` first:

```
int i = 4;
int * p = &i;
```

Comment: In C++, `NULL` couldn't be `(void*)0`, since that isn't implicitly convertible to any other pointer type. It would have to be a null pointer constant such as `0`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I actually wasn't aware of the C++ tag at first. In proper C++, it would of course be `nullptr`. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar As we say that when we assign 0 to pointer it means its point to nothing but indeed it points to some memory location. So what exactly meaning of points to nothing ?

Comment: @VikasVerma: By definition the memory address 0 may not hold a valid data object. It is, literally, an "illegal" address. Is that what your question was about?

Answer (score 3):

you can directly set the address of a pointer in c:

```
char * p  = reinterpret_cast<char *>( 0x0000ffff ) ;
```

Note that is not generally considered safe use of pointers for obvious reasons (can point anywhere in memory).

for more info see [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html) and related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532000/how-to-assign-pointer-address-manually-in-c-programming-language)

Comment: Also, `sizeof( int * )` might not be `4`. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar indeed, it would be machine specific

Answer (score 3):

No it does not break the rule. The integer constant `0` (and generally any constant expression evaluating to 0) is treated specially and it is allowed to assign such value to a pointer. It does not mean that you can assign any integer - just zero.

The current version of C++ introduces the new `nullptr` keyword which should be used instead.

Comment: IIRC, only the literal `0` has this magic property, while e.g. `1 - 1` doesn't.

Comment: @molbdnilo Quite the opposite. Any integer constant expression evaluation to zero can be a null-pointer constant. The property can be used to implement an `isAnIntegerConstant` macro.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is different in C from C++ IIRC. In C++ `0` is special literal that, by definition, can be interpreted as a null pointer of any pointer type; so in this case there is *no* cast from integer to pointer. To test this you can try doing this:

```
int i = 0;
int* p = i;
```

Which you will discover gives an error (See here for [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/zPCCyp) example)

Comment: actually that is not a difference between C and C++. In C, any "constant integer expression of value 0" can serve as a null pointer. (Beware that the term "constant integer expression" is more restrictive in C than in C++, though)

Comment: @JensGustedt: Fair enough. I stand corrected, I had an idea it was different in C and that was where all those `#defined NULL (void*)0`s came from but I've never really worked in C much.

Answer (score 1):

In fact literal `0` or any constant value that is zero is an exception. It could assign to a pointer and it means a `NULL` or `nullptr`. In reverse, any null pointer evaluates to `0`.

Null does not point to any memory address location, its compiler's responsibility to handle it. It is null and null is nowhere in the memory. It points to nothing.

Comment: As we generally say that when we assign 0 to pointer it means its point to nothing but indeed it points to some memory location. So what exactly meaning of points to nothing ?

Comment: @VikasVerma: No it does not point to any memory address location, its compiler's responsibility to handle it. It is null and null is nowhere in the memory. It points to nothing.

Comment: As when I print p output comes 000000 so what its actually mean ?

Comment: @VikasVerma: Compiler evaluates null to `0` and then you see zero in the output.