# C pointer own declaration instead adresse

Tags: c, pointers

Is the expression

```
int* a = 2;
```

in a C/C++ program legal? It doesn't work in visual studio but in other compilers. I'm not sure if it even makes sense to use "random" number for a pointer instead of an fix adresse.

Comment: What is the point of this expression. You don't know what is at memory address 2. This will result in undefined behavior and your program will be almost guaranteed to crash.

Comment: Legal - yes. But not useful, because you can't dereference this pointer without violating memory (unless some very specific use-cases where you know for sure the address `2` is accessible and containing something useful)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign integer literal to pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203381/assign-integer-literal-to-pointer)

Comment: Yes, thank's. That were my thought's.