# How to assign double* value to double* queue[i]?

Tags: c++, pointers, types, variable-assignment

I would like to assign integer 1 to double* queue[i].. I need to convert int 1 to double* type value first before I can assign it to queue[i].. How to code this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt, and [edit] your question to show it together with a detailed description of the problems with it (as long as a description of the problem you try to solve).

Comment: You can't convert `1` to a `double*`. Please read [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to assign integer 1 to double* queue[i]

I think you meant to add the value 1 into your queue:

`queue[i] = new double(1.0);`

Assigning a direct address is a different [story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532000/how-to-assign-pointer-address-manually-in-c-programming-language).

> I need to convert int 1 to double* type value first before I can
>   assign it to queue[i]

That's not how your dynamic `queue` works. It stores the address of newly allocated memory for every `double`. The `new` operator is used for this purpose and it will return the necessary pointer, you just need to do the dynamic memory allocation properly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to assign a direct address to a pointer variable? You had better use `&` operator or `+`, `++` operators on known functions or variables to get the addresses. It's unsafe and not recommended to hardcode address in code. Each time the program is loaded into memory, it could be a different memory space, so the hardcoded address will cause segmentation fault.

See the following example. Either `queue[1]` assignment or `queue[2]` assignment is not recommended.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 10

void print(double *p, int i)
{
    printf("queue[%d]=%p\t*queue[%d]=%.2f\n", i, p, i, *p);
}

int main()
{
    double *queue[MAX_SIZE];
    double dval = 3.5f;
    int ival = 1;

    queue[0] = &dval;
    print(queue[0], 0); 
    // queue[0]=0x7ffee2bfca20  *queue[0]=3.50

    queue[1] = &ival;
    print(queue[1], 1); 
    // queue[1]=0x7ffee2bfca1c  *queue[1]=0.00

    queue[2] = ((double *)1);
    print(queue[2], 2); 
    // zsh: segmentation fault

    return 0;
}
```